# Spark (python): How to 'join' two dataframes where only first occurrences would merge

Tags: python, join, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am looking for a solution for pyspark, but would be happy with the idea/how to solve it in pandas as well. Imagine you have two data frames likes this:

```
+----+---+
|name| _2|
+----+---+
|   A| 10|
|   A| 22|
|   A| 30|
|   B|  2|
|   B|  3|
|   D| 14|
+----+---+

+----+----+
|name|   t|
+----+----+
|   A|true|
|   B|true|
|   C|true|
+----+----+
```

You want to get the result, where only first occurrences get merged, something like this:

```
+----+---+-----+
|name| _2|    t|
+----+---+-----+
|   A| 10| true|
|   A| 22|false|
|   A| 30|false|
|   B|  2| true|
|   B|  3|false|
|   D| 14|false|
+----+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function on your first dataframe:

First let's create our dataframes:

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([["A",10],["A",22],["A",30],["B",2],["B",3],["D",14]]), ["name","_2"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([["A",True],["B",True],["C",True]]), ["name","t"])
```

Next we'll add a column `"rn"` to enumerate rows in `df1` and which will always equal `1` in `df2`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
w = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("_2")
df1 = df1.withColumn("rn", psf.row_number().over(w))
df2 = df2.withColumn("rn", psf.lit(1))

    +----+---+---+
    |name| _2| rn|
    +----+---+---+
    |   B|  2|  1|
    |   B|  3|  2|
    |   D| 14|  1|
    |   A| 10|  1|
    |   A| 22|  2|
    |   A| 30|  3|
    +----+---+---+

    +----+----+---+
    |name|   t| rn|
    +----+----+---+
    |   A|true|  1|
    |   B|true|  1|
    |   C|true|  1|
    +----+----+---+
```

We can now use a `left join`on columns `"name", "rn"`:

```py
df = df1.join(df2, ["name", "rn"], "leftouter")

    +----+---+---+----+
    |name| rn| _2|   t|
    +----+---+---+----+
    |   A|  3| 30|null|
    |   A|  1| 10|true|
    |   A|  2| 22|null|
    |   B|  1|  2|true|
    |   D|  1| 14|null|
    |   B|  2|  3|null|
    +----+---+---+----+
```

We want column `"t"` to be `False` not `null` when it didn't match, we can use a `when`, `otherwise` clause or the function `coalesce`:

```py
df = df.withColumn("t", psf.coalesce(df.t, psf.lit(False)))

    +----+---+---+-----+
    |name| rn| _2|    t|
    +----+---+---+-----+
    |   A|  3| 30|false|
    |   A|  1| 10| true|
    |   A|  2| 22|false|
    |   B|  1|  2| true|
    |   D|  1| 14|false|
    |   B|  2|  3|false|
    +----+---+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe a left outer join will the do trick. After the left outer join, you will have to replace the `null` values with `false`.

Read more about left outer joins here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join